# How to drop trailing and leading rows [Pandas]

Tags: pandas

I wish to remove a subset of leading and trailing rows is essence keeping the middle section. I have to do it this way because if i do it in two parts, the index gets screwed up.

For example if i want to drop the first and last 10 rows

```
df.drop(df.index[:10], inplace=True)
df.drop(df.index[-10:], inplace=True)
```

I wish to do this but in one line or at least make it index safe

Answer (score 0):

Try with `numpy.r_`

```
df.drop(df.index[np.r_[:10,-10:]], inplace=True)
```